# Returning x amount of y characters based on the length of z

Tags: c

Right now I am trying to create a function that takes the length of a string and a character and it is supposed to output x amount of characters.

For example:

```
// char *string = "Hello"; (not actual code)
get_chars(strlen(string), "*"); // #=> *****
```

But I keep getting casting errors and I simply cannot find a solution to the problem. The function I am using is:

```
char
*get_chars(int number, char *ch)
{
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[number];

    for (i; i < number; i++)
    {
         buffer[i] = ch;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Which, when called, produces:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: `buffer[i]` is a `char` and `ch` is a `char *`, this assignment is incompatible. Maybe you meant `ch[0]`. But in any case, you attempt to return a pointer to an array which is destroyed when the function returns, this plan is never going to work.

Comment: Yes, the function is declared before it is called. And how is it destroyed?

Comment: When you declare a variable inside `{ }`, the variable is destroyed when execution exits that scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all let's check the arguments of your function:

```
char *get_chars(int number, char *ch)
```

Ok so we have a method which accepts a number, a pointer to a `char` and returns a pointer to a `char`. Now the intent of the method is to generate a string composed by the same `char` repeated `number` times, so why are you passing a `char*` instead that a `char`?

It doesn't make sense to pass a `char*` unless you really want to pass the pointer to an existing single `char` instead that directly the character, but I don't see any reason to do it in your case, so your signature should become

```
char* get_chars(int number, char ch)
```

Now, `buffer[i] = ch;` assignment doesn't create any problem, and your cast error disappeared.

Then let's see what happens inside the function:

```
char buffer[number];
...
return buffer;
```

So a variable length array is created as a local variable on the stack, and then its address decays to a `char*` pointer, which is returned. But after returning from the function, the local stack is cleared and the address you just returned doesn't make any sense anymore. Here you could have two solutions:

- pass a `char*` to be filled by the method (and allocated by the caller)
- allocate memory in the callee minding that then you'll need to `free` it

First solution translates to something like:

```
void get_chars(char* buffer, int length, char ch) {
  ...
}
```

While second solution would be something like:

```
char* get_chars(int length, char ch) {
  char* buffer = calloc(length+1, 1);
  ...
  return buffer;
}
```

Mind that I'm using `length+1` because a C string is supposed to be NUL terminated by `\0` or any library function won't be able to know where it ends.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is an array of `char`

So, `buffer[i]` is a `char`.

But `ch` is a `char *`.

So `buffer[i] = ch` throws an error.

Either change `ch` to a `char` and pass values accordingly (`'*'` instead of `"*"`), or do `buffer[i] = ch[0]`.

Regardless, you can't just return `buffer`; it's destroyed when the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

Change `char *ch` to `char ch`, and your call from `get_chars(strlen(string), "*");` to `get_chars(strlen(string), '*');`.

Comment: `printf %s` which this is used for requires `char *` though, should I cast it to type `char *`?

Comment: You can use `%c` when you want to print `char` instead of `char *`.